# Mysqli about security in a function

Tags: php, mysqli

```
function get_articles_on_home(){
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY position ASC"
        $output = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        confirm_query($output);
        return($output); 

    }
```

Should I prepare this function securely or encode data, or is it fine since the user is not entering anything at this point?  And if so, how would I do it? Thanks

Comment: This is just fine, no way to inject anything in that query. There's a semicolon missing though.

Comment: Ya I spotted the semi colon after I got an Error. Someday :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't deal with any user input there is no way of injecting your query, but you have a syntax error, probably a typo. You are missing a semicolon `;` right after your query

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY position ASC"; //here was missing
```